# Google Earth Engine gamma correction factor (Image Visualization Parameter) output seems reversed

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

References online state that with a gamma correction (contrast selection), if a gamma value is less than 1 (gamma compression), this expands the low (dark) input values into a wider range of output values. The result is an enhancement of the dark areas of an image (dark regions are made lighter). Conversely, if a gamma value is greater than 1 (gamma expansion), shadows are made darker.

**Why is this reversed in Google Earth Engine, where setting a gamma value to *greater* than 1 brightens the image?**

```
var image = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1/LC08_044034_20140318');
Map.centerObject(image);
Map.addLayer(image, {bands: 'B5,B4,B3'}, 'no_gamma_correction');
Map.addLayer(image, {bands: 'B5,B4,B3', gamma: 0.6}, 'gamma_less_than_one');
Map.addLayer(image, {bands: 'B5,B4,B3', gamma: 1.6}, 'gamma_greater_than_one');
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction

https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/gamma-correction.html

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LVLrEOfQh1Y

Gamma Compression example:
[image: Gamma Corrections]
Source: Gonzalez, Rafael; Woods, Richard; *Digital Image Processing*, Second Edition, Prentice Hall, Upper Saddler River, New Jersey, USA, 2002.

Gamma Compression (left) vs Expansion (right):
[image: Gamma Corrections]
Source: https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/gamma-correction.html

[image: GEE image no gamma correction]
[image: GEE image gamma less than one]
[image: GEE image gamma greater than one]